# Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).style is undefined

Tags: javascript

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).style is undefined" when i click a button referenced in the following script:

```
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  var current = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  current.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Do you have an idea hwat the problem could be? There are definitely a lot of p-Tags on the page.

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a **list** of elements. You'll have to iterate through the list and alter the style of each element individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
    btnContainer.querySelectorAll(".btn")
    .forEach((element) =>
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //your function here
     } );
```

Maybe try something like this. It will make a NodeList of your elements and then you add an evenlistener for each one of them and add your wanted function.